# maximum value of $xy+yz+zx.$ given $x+2y+z=4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

if $x+2y+z=4$ and $x,y,z$ are real number. then find maximum value of $xy+yz+zx$

putting $x+z=4-2z$ in $y(x+z)+zx = y(4-2z)+zx = 4y-2yz+zx$

i wan,t be able to  go further,could some help me with this

Comment: Is it $x^2y+z=4$?

Comment: Could we do this using calculus? Using Lagrange multipliers?  With that, we find that it's sufficient to find $x,y,z,\lambda$ such that
$$
y + z = \lambda\\
x + z = 2\lambda\\
y + z = \lambda\\
x + 2y + z = 4
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $z=4-x-2y$, 
$$\begin{align}xy+yz+zx&=xy+y(4-x-2y)+(4-x-2y)x\\&=xy+4y-xy-2y^2+4x-x^2-2xy\\&=-x^2+(4-2y)x-2y^2+4y\\&=-(x^2+(2y-4)x)-2y^2+4y\\&=-\left((x+y-2)^2-(y-2)^2\right)-2y^2+4y\\&=-(x+y-2)^2+(y-2)^2-2y^2+4y\\&=-(x+y-2)^2-y^2+4\\&\le 4\end{align}$$
The equality is attained when $x+y-2=y=0$, i.e. $x=2,y=0,z=2$.

Answer (score 3):

$$xy+yz+zx+y^2 = (x+y)(y+z) \le \frac{(x+2y+z)^2}{4} = 4$$

$$\Rightarrow xy+yz+zx \le 4-y^2 \le 4$$

Equality occurs when $y=0$, $x=z=2$

Answer (score 2):

$$xy+z(x+y)=xy+(4-x-2y)(x+y)=4x+4y-x^2-2y^2-2xy=k\text{(say)}$$

$$x^2+2x(y-2)+2y^2-4y-k=0$$

As $x$ is real, the discriminant $$4(y-2)^2-4(2y^2-4y-k)\ge0$$

The equality occurs if $x=-\dfrac{2(y-2)}2$

$$\iff k\le4-y^2\le4$$
The equality occurs if $y^2=0$

Comment: @mathlove, Really! please find the updated asnwer

Comment: Maybe you meant "The equality occurs if $y^2=0$".

Comment: @mathlove, thanks for your response.